# How to change password of the .sparseimage encrypted image on El Capitan?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, dmg

I have an encrypted .sparseimage, and can't change password. Don't see any option in Disk Utility. Is it possible and how to change password of the .sparseimage encrypted image on El Capitan?

Answer (score 11):

#### Option 1: Disk Utility

In Disk Utility: select the image in the sidebar, then **File** → **Change Password...**

(You must [unmount](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/disk-utility-changing-disk-image-passwords) the image before you can reset it).

#### Option 2: Terminal

In Terminal:

```
hdiutil chpass <image>
```

More info: [`man hdiutil`](https://ss64.com/osx/hdiutil.html)

Comment: In the current version of OS X, Disk Utility doesn't seem to allow resetting passwords on a sparsebundle image, so you'll need to use the `hdiutil chpass` method.

Comment: Option 2 is the way to go for High Sierra too, even with an APFS encrypted disk or disk image.